# Prerender.io conflicting with CRUD in AngularJs application

Tags: angularjs, nginx, seo, google-crawlers, prerender

I am using prerender.io to make my AngularJS website crawlable.

However, since I started using prerender.io, the majority of my CRUD requests (e.g. update, delete) return an nginx 405 Not Allowed response.

**Original (working) nginx location block** (before using prerender.io):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

**Current location block** (Fetch as Google correctly displays static html, CRUD does not work):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @prerender;
}
```

**Current prerender block**

```
location @prerender {
    proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token D3Ft1yU7Ho3nNMwvgQQO;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~ "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {

        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }
    if ($prerender = 0) {
        rewrite .* / break;
    }
}
```

I believe that the problem is caused either by my current location block or my rewrite statement.

I tried several alternatives for both. e.g.:

```
#CRUD works, FETCH as google does not work
try_files $uri $uri/  @prerender /index.php?$query_string;

#CRUD works, FETCH as google does not work
try_files $uri @prerender $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

#CRUD does not work, FETCH does work
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string  @prerender; 

rewrite .* /index.html break; 
rewrite .* /?$query_string break;
rewrite .* /index.php?$query_string break;
```

etc.

However, in all these configurations EITHER crud works OR prerendering the HTML correctly, never both. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: just fyi, if you set .js .css $prerender 0, prerender version will be just blank page.

Comment: Same problem, can you show your config nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surprisingly, after the latest Ubuntu update, the last rewrite mentioned in my question (rewrite .* /index.php?$query_string;) did the trick. I am not sure why.